# EndpointNotFoundException was unhandled (WCF)

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

I'm following this tuto to deploy a WCF between my sql server and my c# app : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGItMZAWkHg

So this is the part of my program:

IService1:

```
namespace WCFCrud
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        Int32 Insert(WCFContact value);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }


    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class WCFContact
    {
        private Int32 contactID;
        private String contactName;
        private String contactAddress;
        private String contactNumber;
        private DateTime contactDOB;
        private Decimal contactIncome;

        [DataMember]
        public Int32 ContactID
        {
            get
            {
                return contactID;
            }
            set
            {
                contactID = value;
            }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string ContactName
        {
            get
            {
                return contactName;
            }
            set
            {
                contactName = value;
            }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string ContactAddress
        {
            get
            {
                return contactAddress;
            }
            set
            {
                contactAddress = value;
            }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string ContactNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return contactNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                contactNumber = value;
            }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime ContactDOB
        {
            get
            {
                return contactDOB;
            }
            set
            {
                contactDOB = value;
            }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public decimal ContactIncome
        {
            get
            {
                return contactIncome;
            }
            set
            {
                contactIncome = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Service1.cs:

```
namespace WCFCrud
{

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        string ConString = "Server="ServerAdress";Database="DatabaseName";Trusted_Connection=True;";
        public int Insert(WCFContact ContactPar)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertContact", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = ContactPar.ContactName;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = ContactPar.ContactAddress;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = ContactPar.ContactNumber;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactDOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ContactPar.ContactDOB;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactIncome", SqlDbType.Money).Value = ContactPar.ContactIncome;
                    con.Open();
                    var ID = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    ContactPar.ContactID = Convert.ToInt32(ID.ToString());
                }
            }
            return ContactPar.ContactID;
        }
        public int Update(WCFContact ContactPar)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.UpdateContact", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ContactPar.ContactID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = ContactPar.ContactName;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = ContactPar.ContactAddress;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = ContactPar.ContactNumber;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactDOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ContactPar.ContactDOB;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactIncome", SqlDbType.Money).Value = ContactPar.ContactIncome;
                    con.Open();
                    var ID = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return ID;
                }
            }
        }
        public List<WCFContact> SelectAll()
        {
            List<WCFContact> SelectList = new List<WCFContact>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.SelectAllContact", con))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                            {
                                SelectList.Add(new WCFContact
                                {
                                    ContactAddress = dr["ContactAddress"].ToString(),
                                    ContactDOB = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ContactDOB"]),
                                    ContactID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ContactID"]),
                                    ContactIncome = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["ContactIncome"]),
                                    ContactName = Convert.ToString(dr["ContactName"]),
                                    ContactNumber = Convert.ToString(dr["ContactNumber"])
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return SelectList;
        }
        public int Delete(WCFContact ContactPar)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.DeleteContact", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ContactPar.ContactID;
                    con.Open();
                    var ID = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return ID;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My console App:

```
namespace WCFCrudConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceRef.Service1Client objClient = new ServiceRef.Service1Client();
            ServiceRef.WCFContact objContact = new ServiceRef.WCFContact();
            objContact.ContactName = "Dominic";
            objContact.ContactNumber = "1234567";
            objContact.ContactIncome = 50000;
            objContact.ContactDOB = DateTime.Now;
            var ID = objClient.Insert(objContact);



        }
    }
}
```

and my app config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:20570/Service1.svc?singleWsdl" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceRef.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

After some searches, I found a topic which suggets to change my line 
http://localhost:20570/Service1.svc but nothing has changed

So if someone has an idea of what I could do?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Your address should be `http://localhost:xxxx/Service1.svc` if anything where xxxx is your port.  Now if you are using IIS Express or whatever its called your port would no doubt be different from `20570`.  Run your service in the debugger and take note of the port in the Windows System Tray.  Plug that port into your client config.  That or host your service in IIS then the addressing becomes much simpler (i.e. http : // localhost/Service1/Service1.svc) and wont change each time

Comment: Yes the port Number is 20570
I  replaced the adress by http://localhost:20570/Service1.svc but I still have the same message

Comment: Use "Add Service Reference" to add the reference to your Web Service. You can use the Discover button if it's being held on the same solution.

Comment: Try to change `ServiceRef.Service1Client objClient = new ServiceRef.Service1Client();` and call the overload of the constructor that has the endpointName as an argument.

Comment: I already added my service reference but I forgot to update it
Now it's working
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass endpoint name as argument in ServiceRef.Service1Client objClient = new ServiceRef.Service1Client();

EndpointNotFoundException occurs only when it's not found by the client, so we have to explicitly pass argument name. It works for me